# AngularJS : Searching for the equivalent string in an array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I want to make a search filter wherein I wanted to search for the status of an item. The status from my DB are int so I made and equivalence of each index.

To explain more, Here is my codes.

MVC Controller

```
public JsonResult GetStatusList()
    { 
        return Json(new string[] {
            ""
            ,"New"
            ,"Processing"
            ,"PR Approved"
            ,"Qouting"
            ,"Qouting Approved"
            ,"PO Processing"
            ,"Closed"
            ,"Cancelled"
            ,"Rejected"
            ,"PO Issued"
            ,"On Delivery"
            ,"Received"
            ,"AP Posting"
            ,"Payment"
            ,"Sourcing"
            ,"Re-Processing"
        },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here's my MVC View

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="model in models  | orderBy: sorting:reverse | filter : filter ">

                    <td>{{jsonDatetotext(model.RequestDate) | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModalContent" data-ng-click="getSelectedPR(model)">{{model.RequestID}}
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{model.PARNumber }}</td>
                    <td>{{model.ProgramName }}</td>
                    <td>{{model.FullName }}</td>
                    <td>{{model.DepartmentName | uppercase}}</td>
                    <td>{{model.PONo}}</td>
                    **<td>{{StatusList[model.StatusID] | uppercase}}</td>**
                    <td class="totalAmount"><span class="pull-right">{{model.TotalAmount | number:2}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{model.InboxLearUID | lowercase}}</td>
                </tr>
```

where I wanted to include the status for search filters. The status can only be search by its ID.

Here is my angular

```
 scope.getStatus = http.get('GetStatusList').success(function (status) {
            scope.StatusList = status;
        });
```

I wanted the status itself will be searched not just its ID.

Comment: I don't see a filter here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this on your angular.
I suggest you use checkbox for your project.

```
    scope.array_ = angular.copy(scope.array);
        scope.getStatus = http.get('GetStatusList').success(function (status) {
            scope.StatusList = status;

        });


        PRApp.directive("checkboxGroup", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    // Determine initial checked boxes
                    if (scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id) !== -1) {
                        elem[0].checked = true;
                    }

                    // Update array on click
                    elem.bind('click', function () {
                        var index = scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id);
                        // Add if checked
                        if (elem[0].checked) {
                            if (index === -1) scope.array.push(scope.item.id);
                        }
                            // Remove if unchecked
                        else {
                            if (index !== -1) scope.array.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                        // Sort and update DOM display
                        scope.$apply(scope.array.sort(function (a, b) {
                            return a - b
                        }));
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```